# How UTF8/Unicode adapt to new writing systems?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, fonts

An example to clarify my question:

The Hongkongers' native language is Cantonese, however, we all write in a different language: Madarin Chinese. Two languages are kindof similar, and Hongkongers are educated to write in Madarin Chinese language.

Cantonese doesn't have a writing system. Though we are still happy with Madarin as our writing language, however, in case one day Hongkongers decided to develop a 'Cantonese script' which contains not-yet-existing characters, how should UTF8/Unicode/fonts change, to adapt these new characters?

I mean, who will change the UTF8/Unicode/fonts standard? How exactly Linux/Windows OS have to be modified, in order to display these newly created characters?

(The example is just to make my question clear. We're not talking about politics ;D )

Comment: There will have to be new Unicode code points, and new fonts that support the characters. Related: http://www.unicode.org/standard/standard.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Unicode coding space has over 1,000,000 code points, and only about 10% of them have been allocated, so there is a lot of room for new characters (even though some areas of the coding space have been set apart for use other than added characters). The Unicode Consortium, working in close cooperation with the relevant body at ISO, assigns code points to new characters on the basis of proposals that demonstrate actual usage or, in some cases, plans with a solid basis and widespread support.

Thus, if a new script were designed and there was a large community that would seriously use it, it would be added, with its characters, into Unicode after due proposals and discussion.

It would then be up to font manufacturers to add glyphs for such characters. This might take a long time, but if there is strong enough need, new fonts and enhancements to existing fonts would emerge.

No change to UTF-8 or other Unicode transfer encodings would be needed. They already encode the entire coding space, whether code points are assigned to characters or not.

Rendering software would need no modifications, unless there are some specialties in the writing system. Normal characters would be rendered just fine, as soon as suitable fonts are available.

However, if the characters added were outside the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), the “16-bit subset of Unicode”, both rendering and processing (and input) would be problematic. Many programming languages and programs effectively treat Unicode as if it were a 16-bit code and run into problems (possibly solvable, but still) when characters outside the BMP are used. If the writing system had, say, 10,000 characters, it is quite possible that it would have to allocated outside the BMP.

Comment: UCS-2 was replaced with UTF-16 a long time ago. Most programming languages have evolved to handle UTF-16. Very few people actually use UCS-2 anymore (UTF-16 is fully backwards compatible with UCS-2, just like UTF-8 is fully backwards compatible with ASCII).

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I wasn’t referring to UCS-2 specifically but to the fact that non-BMP characters cause considerable problems. For example, they typically need to be represented as surrogate pairs in strings, so that the length of a string does not equal the number of characters in it.

Comment: They don't cause "considerable" problems, because most people who are aware of UTF-16 do know that surrogates have to be handled. And UTF-7, UTF-8, even MBCS, are variable-length encodings, so the "length!=chars" catch has been an issue for a LONG time. It is mostly people who limit themselves to ASCII/Latin encodings that have ignored that fact.

Answer (score 0):

The Unicode committee adds new characters as they see fit. Then fonts add support for the new characters. Operating systems should not require changes simply to display the new characters. Typing the characters would generally require updates or plug-ins to an operating system's input methods.